# prepare to segue pass data selector

Tags: iphone, ios, selector, segue

I'm trying to pass data through through segues with this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseDetailDescription"]) {
    SoulExerciseDetailQuarViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setOverview:)]) {
        NSDictionary *overview = @{@"name" : [_exercise objectForKey:@"name"], @"longDescription" : [_exercise objectForKey:@"longDescription"]};
        [destination setValue:overview forKey:@"overview"];

    }
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseDetailGear"]) {
    SoulExerciseDetailTriaViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelectedGearString:)]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *selectedGearString = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
        [destination setValue:selectedGearString forKey:@"selectedGearString"];

    } 
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseDetailCategory"]) {
    SoulExerciseDetailDuaViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelectedCategoryString:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Go");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *selectedCategoryString = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

        [destination setValue:selectedCategoryString forKey:@"selectedCategoryString"];

    }
}}
```

So if it responds to the setter that is found in the segue's destination it allows the transfer of data.

The weird thing is that the first one responds correctly but in the second and third, it says that the destination view controller is not responding to those setter

For example in the third the nslog is not shown.

Comment: it says navigation controller

Comment: between the class that starts the segue and the class in which it arrives there is a navigation controller to give the navigation bar to the destination since its modal segue. I'm trying to set destination as the navigation controller and get its root view controller but it doesnt allow that.

Comment: Never mind, did it. How do i accept your answer?

Comment: I put the comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from previous comments:

NSLog the destination class:

```
NSLog(@"class name: %@", NSStringFromClass([destination class]));
```

My bet is that the class is not what you think.

OP: "it says navigation controller"

Which isn't what you expect, correct? So figure out why the wrong thing is being instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I forgot to change the class from default UIViewController to my extended view controller.